# Populating combobox in VB from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have actually done some research on this, and result is shown in my work. But I am still having problems populating the combobox. The form runs fine with no errors, but nothing shows up in the combobox. Can anyone help with this issue? I keep running it over, but I have absolutely no idea where the problem is.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub cboModel_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboModel.SelectedIndexChanged

    Try
        Dim strSelect As String = ""
        Dim cmdSelect As OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim drSourceTable As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable

        If OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer() = False Then

            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Database connection error." & vbNewLine &
                                "The application will now close.",
                                Me.Text + "Error",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

            Me.Close()

        End If

        cboModel.BeginUpdate()

        cboModel.Items.Clear()

        strSelect = "SELECT intAutoID, strMake FROM TAutos"

        cmdSelect = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, m_conAdministrator)
        drSourceTable = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader

        dt.Load(drSourceTable)

        cboModel.ValueMember = "intAutoID"
        cboModel.DisplayMember = "strMake"
        cboModel.DataSource = dt

        If cboModel.Items.Count > 0 Then cboModel.SelectedIndex = 0

        cboModel.EndUpdate()
        drSourceTable.Close()
        CloseDatabaseConnection()


    Catch excError As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(excError.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    Dim strSelect As String = ""
    Dim strModel As String = ""
    Dim cmdSelect As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim drSourceTable As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable

    If OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer() = False Then
        MessageBox.Show(Me, "Database Connection Error." & vbNewLine &
                        "The Application Will Now Close.",
                         Me.Text + "Error",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        Me.Close()
    End If

    strSelect = "SELECT strMake, strModel, strYear, strMileage FROM TAutos WHERE intAutoID = " & cboModel.SelectedValue

    cmdSelect = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, m_conAdministrator)
    drSourceTable = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader

    dt.Load(drSourceTable)

    txtMake.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(0)
    txtMileage.Text = dt.Rows(1).Item(1)
    txtYear.Text = dt.Rows(2).Item(2)

    CloseDatabaseConnection()


End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    Dim strSelect As String = ""
    Dim strMake As String = ""
    Dim strMileage As String = ""
    Dim strYear As String = ""
    Dim intRowsAffected As Integer

    Dim cmdUpdate As OleDb.OleDbCommand

    If OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer() = False Then
        MessageBox.Show(Me, "Database Connection Error." & vbNewLine &
                        "The Application Will Now Close.",
                         Me.Text + "Error",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        Me.Close()
    End If

    strMake = txtMake.Text
    strMileage = txtMileage.Text
    strYear = txtYear.Text

    strSelect = "Update TAutos Set strMake = '" & strMake & "', " & "strMileage = '" & strMileage & "', " & "strYear = '" & strYear & "', " & "Where intAutoID = " & cboModel.SelectedValue

    MessageBox.Show(strSelect)

    cmdUpdate = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, m_conAdministrator)

    intRowsAffected = cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()

    If intRowsAffected = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Update Failed")
    End If

    CloseDatabaseConnection()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: "no idea"?   Does that mean you haven't tried running the code in the debugger and peeking into the `DataTable` after it loads?   Try that and tell us the result.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and confirmed that `m_conAdministrator` is an open connection, with read permissions for your DB, etc?

Comment: Before you do anything you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. My friend bobby tables loves code like this. http://bobby-tables.com/